# Reaction mechanism for ozonolysis

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, ozone

I have been trying to understand the reaction mechanism for ozonolysis but I am not able to understand what happens after the intermediate trioxolane is formed. I have searched online but didn't really get any intuitive understanding. Can you provide an explanation of how the reaction proceeds after trioxolane is formed?

Comment: You might want to run further online searches for *ozonolysis + reductive workup* (typically using zinc metal or dimethyl sulfide) and *ozonolysis + oxidative workup* (typically with hydrogen peroxide).

Comment: @KlausWarzecha I tried that but most sites give very brief information about them. Can you share any link which you feel is good enough to explain it?

Comment: Try searching for the Criegee mechanism (not Criegee rearrangement).  This is well established for ozonolysis of mono, di- and tri-substituted alkenes. Try here Angew. Chem. Int. Ed., 1975, 87, 745

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/mechanismmordor/_/rsrc/1391158462221/first-year-mechanisms/ozonolysis/Criegee%20mechanism.jpg

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7117/ozonolysis-conditions-for-benzene